# How to compute sum with non consecutive indices in Maple?

Tags: maple

Suppose we need to compute the sum in Maple,

$
\sum_{i = 0}^{10} 2^i
$,

We can use the command,

```
sum(2^i, i = 0 .. 10)
```

Now, what if the indices are not consecutive like `i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, [no 5], 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`?

I tried `sum(2^i, i = {0 .. 4, 6 .. 10})` but no luck.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/) is a better site for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the command "add" for instance

> $$\rm {add}( 2^i, i=[0,1,2,5,6,9,10] )=1639.$$

Type in maple worksheet the following command $>?list$ to read about "list".

Comment: Thanks. If part of the sequence is consecutive, is there a way to use `..` operator to generate that partial consecutive sequence then combine it with the rest of the whole sequence?

Comment: @divingswallow: Try to use the sequence command in maple to generate the partial sequences, for example $ \rm{seq} ( j, j=0..4 ) $.

Comment: Thank you, it works; `add(2^i, i = [seq(j, j = 0 .. 4), seq(k, k = 6 .. 10)]) = 2015`. Happy new year!!

Comment: @divingswallow: Good job! You are very welcome.

Comment: Use the dollar sign operator for a briefer command: add(2^i, i= [\$1..4, \$6..10])

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use

```
sum(2^i, i = 0 .. 10)-2^5
```